# codeigniter timespan function starts from 1 hour?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter 3.0.3

When i use timespan starts from 1 hour not from 1 second

Here's my code

```
$post_date = $post->post_date;
$now = time();
$units = 1;
echo timespan($post_date, $now, $units);
```

i'm using it inside foreach loop in my view and $post->post_date = 1450879391

Comment: What exactly does `echo timespan($post_date, $now, $units);` return to you?

Comment: does `timespan(1450879391, 1450879392, 1)` also give you one hour?  As codeigniter is open source, you may also have a look inside the function and see what it is doing :)

Comment: it was return 1 hour when i add new post but it solved i was using local_to_gmt in insert to database function i used gmt_to_local instead of it now starts from 0

Comment: ahh ok, good to hear

Comment: Answer your own post that will help for others